# wordpress a tag onClick issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, onclick

im having some troubles integrating my home-brewed slideshow jQuery script into wordpress.

so far i have learned the hard way that you must integrate scripts using wp_enqueue_script, but now i encounter that my onclick on a tag fon run my functions, functions i use to change slide etc. etc.

in my home-brewed slideshow script i have wrapped all my jQuery code into a wrapper

```
(function($) { // OPEN WRAPPER
  // SCRIPTS
})(jQuery); // CLOSE WRAPPER
```

to explain my problem better here is some theoretical dummy code:

jQuery slide script:

```
(function($) { // OPEN WRAPPER

$(window).load(function() {
// INIT my slideshow
});

function callJsFunction(num){
alert("function executed perfectly"+num);
};

})(jQuery); // CLOSE WRAPPER
```

Html file:

```
...
<a href="#" onclick="callJsFunction(3); return false"> CLICK ME </a>
...
```

No matter what i try in Wordpress 3.7.x the bloody function wont run, any idea to why this is not working ?, i've googled for ages but did not find an answer, any articles about newbie's-home-brewing for jQuery to WP would also be appreciated :D

Comment: don't wrap your function otherwise it's only available inside its wrapper scope

Answer (score 2):

`callJsFunction` is inside another self executing functions scope, and it's not available outside the scope of that function, so you can't call if from the anchor.

```
(function($) { // creates new scope (and BTW does not wait for DOM ready)

    function callJsFunction(num){} // only available inside this scope

})(jQuery);
```

remove the inline event handler:

```
<a href="#" id="something_unique" data-num="3"> CLICK ME </a>
```

and use jQuery

```
jQuery(function($) {
     $('#something_unique').on('click', function() {
          var num = $(this).data('num');
          alert("function executed perfectly" + num);
     });
});
```

Comment: Aha, hmmm this could be a serious problem for my script since i am calling a lot of functions which is running jQuery code.

another Pseudocode:

**text**function callJsFunction(num){
$(".slide-id-"+num).fadeIn(300);
};**text**

would it be better to skip the wrapper and replace all $(..) with jQuery(..) in my script ?, is that a more approved method ?, im kind of learning here ;).

another approach which comes to my mind would be to wrap the main jQuery code in a wrapper and then use the jQuery(...) in my functions ?... 

which approach would a real master choose :).
thanks in advance :)

Comment: You can skip the wrapper and use jQuery instead of $, but then you have to move the script out of the head and include it just before the closing body tag. Wordpress has an option for that when including scripts.

Comment: ohhh crap.. this is bad news for my script, crap.. i'll properly have to do some tests hmmm. but thanks for the quick respons :)

Comment: You could just set your function on global scope and keep your wrapper: `window.callJsFunction = function(num) {...}`